# Parallel clustered columnstore index build

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

Is it possible to build clustered columnstore index using several processes and keeping the row order of clustered rowstore index? Table is partitioned. Currently I am converting rowstore index to columnstore like this:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED columnstore INDEX [index_name] ON schema.table
    WITH (
            drop_existing = ON
            ,MAXDOP = 1
            )
```

If I increase MAXDOP, then row order isn't kept. I am thinking about creating separate table for every partition and then doing partition switching. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "row order" since tables are, by definition, unordered.

Comment: I meant how first columns of index are alocated between row groups. If CCI is built from CRI, then [row group elimination](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2017/01/30/columnstore-segment-elimination/) can be used.